# Passing custom attributes to an authorize.net checkout page

Tags: authorize.net

We're going to build a portal for an authorize.net merchant. A page in this portal will have a button that will navigate to an authorize.net hosted checkout page.

Is it possible to pass custom metadata to that page which will get stored in authorize.net when the payment is complete? The goal is to allow the merchant to have a reference to the customer's identity in our system.

Comment: Are you using the accept.js API?

Comment: @JohnConde I'm not familiar with accept.js. What we're looking for is to just redirect the user from our platform to an authorize.net-hosted checkout page. So no logic at our end. The only thing we want to do is pass that hosted form a custom customer identifier from our end to later identify which customer in our system made the payment. Is this doable in accept.js?

Comment: @JohnConde any insight on my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

One Authorize.net Get Accept Hosted parameter designed for this purpose would be the **refId** (string, up to 20 characters). Which is a merchant-assigned reference ID for the request.
If included in the request, this value is included in the response.
E.g.,

```
{
  "getHostedPaymentPageRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
      "name": "LOGIN",
      "transactionKey": "TRANSACTION_KEY"
    },
 "refId": "123456",       
    
"transactionRequest": {
      "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
      "amount": "20.00",
      "profile": {
        "customerProfileId": "123456789"
      },
      "customer": {
        "email": "ellen@example.com"
      },
      "billTo": {
        "firstName": "Ellen",
        "lastName": "Johnson",
        "company": "Souveniropolis",
        "address": "14 Main Street",
        "city": "Pecan Springs",
        "state": "TX",
        "zip": "44628",
        "country": "US"
      }
    },
    "hostedPaymentSettings": {
      "setting": [{
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentReturnOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"showReceipt\": true, \"url\": \"https://example.com/receipt\", \"urlText\": \"Continue\", \"cancelUrl\": \"https://example.com/cancel\", \"cancelUrlText\": \"Cancel\"}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentButtonOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"text\": \"Pay\"}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentStyleOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"bgColor\": \"blue\"}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentPaymentOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"cardCodeRequired\": false, \"showCreditCard\": true, \"showBankAccount\": true}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentSecurityOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"captcha\": false}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentShippingAddressOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"show\": false, \"required\": false}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentBillingAddressOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"show\": true, \"required\": false}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentCustomerOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"showEmail\": false, \"requiredEmail\": false, \"addPaymentProfile\": true}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentOrderOptions",
        "settingValue": "{\"show\": true, \"merchantName\": \"G and S Questions Inc.\"}"
      }, {
        "settingName": "hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl",
        "settingValue": "{\"url\": \"https://example.com/special\"}"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```